# Why Mybatis deem null passed from controller as String type "null"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mybatis

Here is how my controller looks like

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<myBean> list(String person){
  Map<String,Object> reqMap = new HashMap();
  reqMap.put("person", person);
  return myService.getList();
}
```

This is Mybatis mapper file

```
<select id="list" resultMap="rs_Bean" parameterType="java.util.Map">
  SELECT * FROM myTable
  <trim prefix="where" prefixOverrides="and | or">
    <if test="null != person">
      AND name = #{person}
    </if>
  </trim>
</select>
```

What I want is if the person field is null then it will not go into sql statement.
 However I found Mybatis deems null as String "null"

> SELECT * FROM myTable where person = ?
>
> Parameters: null(String)

Could you let me know what causes the problem and the way to solve it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your condition backwards?

Comment: @shmosel   there is no difference